# Chinese proverb equivalent? "Hitting a dog with baozi"

Tags: idiom-requests

Background: "baozi" is any of several varieties of big, soft steamed buns filled with meat, veg, and seasonings: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baozi

There's a phrase in Mandarin which translates to "hitting a dog with baozi," which is a phrase used to describe someone approaching a problem in the wrong way, so much so that what they're doing is actually detrimental.

If you throw soft, tasty food at a dog because it did something wrong, you're likely to make the problem worse. And you've also deprived yourself of the food.

In English, the only thing I can think of that's sort of close would be "invading Russia in the winter," but I don't think it's quite the same, as it doesn't carry the same "making things worse" connotation.

Comment: Pouring gasoline on a flame

Comment: "out of the frying pan into the fire"?

Comment: put lipstick on a pig

Comment: Seems to be how the US Government punishes bank executives who break the law or cause global economic catastrophe...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In very similar vein to some other suggestions, but I think with the connotation that you desire:

***Using kerosene to put out a fire***  is clearly applying a "solution" that will make your situation worse.

Comment: nice! It's very close to "adding fuel to fire" but it doesn't mean the same.

Answer (score 1):

***Do more harm than good:***

> - to make a situation worse instead of better

***Add fuel to the fire/flames:***

> - to make a bad situation even worse by saying or doing something that makes someone angry

or:

***Make matters/things worse***:

> - used for talking about something that makes a bad situation worse.

([macmillandictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/to-make-something-worse))

Comment: "Do more harm than good" is what I'm looking for. Deep down, I was hoping for something a little cuter.

I think "adding fuel to the fire," etc. is a little different from what I was looking for. If I say "stop adding fuel to the fire," to someone, then they know exactly what they're doing, but if I say "stop hitting the dog with baozi," it's meant to point out to them that what they're doing is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

***Go from bad to worse*** - to progress from a bad situation to one that is worse (http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+from+bad+to+worse)

Answer (score 0):

The extreme form of this behavior can be described as **snatching defeat from the jaws of victory**.

Comment: Doesn't this mean losing a game from a strong winning position? How is it related to making something worse by adopting the wrong approach?

Comment: @BiscuitBoy - Exactly. You've got the game won, and then you do something stupid and blow it. Like I said, it's the extreme version.